# Measure the window width continuously and not only on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a column layout on my WP-site. Column 1 contains some text and column 2 contains some images. I'm now in the process of making the site responsive. When looking at mobile phones, I wanted the images to be above the text, instead of below.

I therefore wrote this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(jQuery(window).width() <= 750) {
    jQuery(".rescol12").insertBefore(".rescol11");
    jQuery(".rescol22").insertBefore(".rescol21");
    jQuery(".rescol32").insertBefore(".rescol31");
  }
</script>
```

This is working fine, on load. But if I load the page fullscreen and resize my browser window on my desktop, the script doesn't kick in.

How can I adjust my if condition, so that it doesn't just measure the window with on load?

Comment: you could listen for `resize` events

Comment: wrap the code in `$(window).resize(function(){ // put the code here  }).resize();` method.

Comment: For design purpose, better is just to use CSS

Comment: Consider using a responsive CSS-Framework, e.g. ``Twitter-Bootstrap``. You do not need any JavaScript to achieve this and it is easy to implement.

Comment: [Here an example](http://jsfiddle.net/fsugue7v/) using [CSS flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) And you can find many other ways i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .resize() will work in this case.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    // code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send resize event to the window element, so it's called every time browser window size is changed.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  // do something
});
```